# Has google closure a contains-function where I can specify the comparing function?

Tags: google-closure-library

I have an array of DateObjects and DateRange-Objects and a single DateObject.

I would like to know if this single Date is in the array of DateObjects or in the range of one DateRange-Object.

[`goog.array.contains(arr, obj)`](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_array_array.js.html) is almost what I want, but I would like the `goog.date.isSameDay(date, opt_now)` function to compare.

**Has google closure a contains-function where I can specify the comparing function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find`/`findIndex` might be what you're looking for. Something like:

```
goog.array.find(dates, goog.partial(goog.date.isSameDay, singleDateObject));
goog.array.findIndex(ranges, function(range) { /* your comparison */ });
```

Comment: You may need to add goog.require('goog.date.Date'). If you're expecting a non-null response, you'll also need to make singleDateObject actually be the same day as one of your test dates.

Comment: Hi nullptr, thanks for your answer. I had made a typo; I thought singleDateObject was the same day as one of the test dates. goog.require('goog.date.Date') had not to be added. Thanks for your help!